# Xamarin axml the layout could not be load - visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I have a problem when I go to open a file with .axml Xamarin, in progetto.droid, visual studio returns me an error saying that I can not load the layout .:

[image]

[image]

I searched online and many say that the solution is clear the cache in the path C: \ Users \ xyz \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ VisualStudio \ 14.0 \ ComponentModelCache, I have deleted this folder, restarted vs, but nothing, the problem I it remains, how do I fix? someone has an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your java version and your android SDK version using the Android SDK manager, this worked for me.

Comment: my android sdk is the last, version 25.2.2, why don't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to downgrade your SDK. Google just released a new version of Android SDK Tools (rev. 24.3). This version breaks the Xamarin.Android designer.

[Here is the solution from official blog](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42333/not-yet-compatible-android-sdk-tools-rev-24-3)